# How can I customize which Gmail notifications are shown in the notification bar?

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, notifications, gmail, notification-bar, filter

I receive dozen of useless newsletters everyday from my school, at the same time the same addresses may send a few important e-mails that I need to read ASAP.

How can I setup the Gmail client and the Android notification bar in such a way that the bar will show new messages only of their title doesn' start with a certain string of characters?

ex. if the same address sends me a newsletter called "Campus news no. xxx" (with the exact title changing everytime) how can I have the notification bar NOT show any message starting with the string "campus news"?

(Android 4.2.2 with Touch Wiz - Samsung Ace 3 GT-7270)

Comment: Well, @maja I wouldn't think that will be possible at all! Anyway I would say you can wait a little while for other members to respond over the same but I don't think the chances of getting the answer to such question is possible at all !

Comment: @PeterCarlos It's possible, but sadly not using Android only. In my opinion, the insufficient label management is a huge issue. I'd love to add, edit or remove labels in the app..

Comment: @stefan Yes, that's what I was thinking but as over here the original poster has been asking about to do the same over the Android device which makes me a little of the ....

Comment: @PeterCarlos in fact I don't care if it is on the device or a desktop, instead I find the desktop tools themselves to be somewhat lacking..  (no alfabetical sort inside the filter, a few to many clicks to get very repetitive processes done, etc. )

Comment: maja in that case I think you have already got your query answered by @stefan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can filter messages based on sender, recipient, subject and other criteria from within the Web app. This is not possible from within the Android app.

1. In a web browser, Goto [Settings] -> [Filters] of Gmail. Click on [Create new filter].
2. Create a filter to match your newsletters.

[image: Try the search to see if your messages are actually matching.]

3. Assign a label to them (create one if you don't have one yet). Make sure to apply "skip the inbox (archive it)" such that this message only lands in that label, but doesn't land in your inbox triggering a notification.

[image: Check "Skip the inbox" and select a label next to "apply the label"]

Now go to label settings in the Android app and customize notifications for the "newsletters" label. 
[image: Your options here are to display no notification at all, or a silent one or a custom ring tone.]

Comment: I eventually arrived to this solution and passed the whole day updating the filters, I somehow feel the whole system may benefit from an overhaul, but at least it should work for the most annoying content. thanks @stefan

Answer (score 1):

If you'd use the new label system you could have easily turned off notifications for that label, otherwise follow what was posted to get the same effect

Comment: how? how can I have a label assigned to some completely new content (either a new combination of sending address and title elements or just a new address form the same domain)?